# How to 'run' an IVR saved in JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, twilio

I am working on a IVR solution for small businesses in my local area but I am having trouble wrapping my head around how Node will handle menus. I *could* make a seperate Node server for each of my customers but I would like to have a single server that pulls each customer's IVR setup from a Mongo database or file when their number is called. I have an idea on how to save the menu structure in JSON but I am lost when it comes to turning that JSON into responses to `<gather>` inputs. I was thinking I could use a JSON structure like this in the DB (or maybe as a .json file on Amazon S3):

```
{
  "menu": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Main",
    "script": "Thank you for calling Local Company. To speak to sales press 1, ...",
    "options": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "action": "",
        "value": "",
        "next": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Sales",
        "action": "dial",
        "value": 12345678901,
        "next": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Support",
        "action": "dial",
        "value": 12345678902,
        "next": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Directions",
        "action": "say",
        "value": "Our offices are located at...",
        "next": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Mailbox",
        "action": "mailbox",
        "value": "main",
        "next": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you can return the JSON based on the number a user is dialling, then you could do something like this:

```
const Twilio = require('twilio');

app.post('/voice', (req, res) => {
  const dialledNumber = req.body.To;
  getIVRObjectFromPhoneNumber(dialledNumber, (IVRObject) => {
    const twiml = Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    if (typeof req.body.Digits !== 'undefined') {
      // A user has pressed a digit, do the next thing!
      const action = IVRObject.menu.options[req.body.Digits]
      twiml[action.action](action.value);
    } else {
      // No digits yet, return the <Gather>
      const gather = twiml.gather({
        numDigits: 1
      });
      gather.say(IVRObject.script);
    }
    res.send(twiml.toString());
  });
});
```

This doesn't quite use all of your object, I'm not sure what the values for `next` mean, but hopefully it's a start. The `getIVRObjectFromPhoneNumber` method is my made up, asynchronous method that returns a JavaScript object parsed from your example JSON above.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! The next parameter is the id of the action to execute next. So an info option could return to a menu or do something else like that. Also, I didn't know you could do twiml[action.action](action.value). I thought i would have to do a switch statement with each command type.

Comment: You can do that `twiml[action.action](action.value)` because of the action names and values that you've picked so far (ie, the action names are the names of both the TwiML verbs you are using, but in their lowercase forms are also the names of the methods on the `twiml` object). It might not work that well for everything, I haven't thought it through yet!